# "Count how many different starting letters are in languages names"

Tags: sort, uniq

So I have this text document with 89 lines. In this document the first column of every line is another language. My task is to count how many different starting letters are used in the document.
I think I have to use some sort of `sort` command with `uniq`, but I am not sure how to do this.

Snapshot from [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/QGWZ7jWr):

```
Adyghe Adygea
Albanian Albania        
Aragonese Aragon
Armenian Armenia, Nagorno-Karabakh
Aromanian
...
Wymysorys Poland
Võro  
Walloon Wallonia
Welsh Wales
```

Answer (score 3):

This ought to cover it

```
cut -c1 filename | sort -u | wc -l
```

Using your data on pastebin it gives a result of 21.

The `cut` just plucks out letter 1, the `sort` has the -u flag for unique, and then piped into `wc` to give a line count.